# How common are invasions when playing as human?

Tags: dark-souls

It's likely that the PC version has the largest playerbase at this point: https://steamdb.info/app/211420/graphs/

For example, how many invasions could I generally expect during 10 hours of gameplay in human form (PC)?

Comment: There are a lot of variables that affect when you might be invaded, such as how long you spend in a particular area before killing the boss, how long you spend hollowed, etc. So I doubt this question has a satisfactory answer unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulO.: The question is now about the human form only.

Comment: When I am in an area, which is appropriate to my level it can be let's say in range of 100-1 invansions per 10 hours.

Comment: Is this aaking about Dark Souls 1 in particular?

Comment: @Ben: Of course, see the tag.

Comment: Just checking. Sometimes people confuse the tags. And from my own experience, while they are still fairly popular within the community, the first game in the series has lost a fair amount of interest from the community, so you'll likely nog see anywhere near as much interaction with other players

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple factors for this:

- Your network setup
- The level you're at relative to the area
- How long you hang around the area before killing the boss
- The area itself

### Your network setup

Dark Souls is a peer-to-peer game.  If you do not have the correct ports forwarded/opened on your network, you won't get invaded.  It just simply won't work because invaders will be unable to connect to you (the host).  When you are being invaded, the victim is the host.

### The level you're at relative to the area

If you are super high level in a super low level area, or vice versa, you will not be invaded due to players generally not looking for victims within those level ranges.

### How long you hang around the area before killing the boss

You can only get invaded if you have not killed the boss.  If you know the game well, and rush the boss, then you won't get invaded nearly as much.

### The area itself

People simply favor certain areas for invasion.